# Grails 3.0.9 and Geb test null request object

Tags: grails, request, functional-testing, geb

As per a user request the behavior of the save action is that it will redirect to whatever page the create action was chosen from.

In this instance that is the referrer.

The issue is that when I try to run a geb test to test this functionality, the redirect doesn't happen and when I look at the value of `requestReferer()` in the geb test, it is `null`, and the value of `request` in the geb test is also `null`

```
// Controller's save action
@Transactional
def save() {
    def baseUrl = baseUrl()

    params.createdBy = currentUser()
    params.contactEmail = userEmail()

    Item item = new Item( params )

    if ( params.group) {
        itemService.bindItemPropertyData( item, params )
    }

    if ( !item.validate() ) {
        if ( item.isSpecialConstraintViolation() ) {
            def duplicatedItemUrl = itemAssetService.getDuplicatedItemUrl( item.source, baseUrl )

            render view: 'create', model: [ item : item,
                                            map             : getListsForView(),
                                            duplicatedSource: duplicatedAssetUrl,
                                            referer         : params.referer,
                                            params          : params ]
        } else {
            render view: 'create', model: [ item: item,
                                            map           : getListsForView(),
                                            referer       : params.referer,
                                            params        : params ]
        }
    } else {
        if ( params.referer ) {
            item.save( flush: true )
            redirect( uri: params.referer )
        } else {
            item.save( flush: true )
            redirect( action: "show", id: item.id )
        }
    }
}

// requestReferer() method in controller
private String requestReferer() {
    return request.getHeader("referer")
}

// Geb login method
def logIn() {
    $("form").username = "user"
    $("form").password = "password"
    $("button").click()
}

// geb test in question
def "test creating an item"() {
    when: "logging in and creating an item"
        go '/'
        logIn()
        go '/item/create'
        $("form").name = "Item One"
        $("form").source = "Item One"
        $("button").click()

    then: "item was saved"
        $("title").text() == "Item Index"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue was that in the test the create action was not being requested through the clicking of a link, this caused the request headers not to be set.

The solution was to actually click on the create link on the page, after making that change the tests passed.